# python: finding a continuous list of values, matching a condition, starting from the first element

Tags: python, arrays, optimization

I'm processing a very large data set.
The data set is made of data profiles, each profile stored in an array.
I need to find, for each array, continuous series of values, including the first one, and matching a condition (value >= 26).

example:

for input values=`[30.1, 29.7, 28.5, 27.1, 20, 17, 16]`

the algorithm returns  `[30.1, 29.7, 28.5, 27.1]`

for input values=`[30.1, 29.7, 28.5, 27.1, 20, 17, 28, 27]`

the algorithm returns `[30.1, 29.7, 28.5, 27.1]`

for input values=`[25, 30.1, 29.7, 28.5, 27.1, 20, 17, 28, 27]`

the algorithm returns `None`

I could parse the array and make a "if" test, but considering I have hundred of thousand of series to analyse, I'm searching for something more optimized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be aptly done through [itertools.takewhile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile), which returns the elements until the predicate is false.

And here is an example to use itertools.takewhile

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> list(takewhile(lambda e:e>=26, [30.1, 29.7, 28.5, 27.1, 20, 17, 16]))
[30.1, 29.7, 28.5, 27.1]
```

For the last example, though it does not return `None`, but an empty iterable, which you can easily mold to suit your requirement

```
>>> list(takewhile(lambda e:e>=26, [25, 30.1, 29.7, 28.5, 27.1, 20, 17, 28, 27]))
[]
```

Comment: It returns `[]` for last example, which btw is probably the right choice.